# Problems with CAGradientLayer

Tags: iphone, ios

Im using the code

```
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.rollBtn,nil];        
for(UIButton *btn in buttons)
{       
    btn.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
    btn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2.0, -3.0);
    btn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    btn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    btnGradient.frame = btn.bounds;
    btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f / 255.0f green:102.0f / 255.0f blue:102.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                          (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:51.0f / 255.0f green:51.0f / 255.0f blue:51.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                          nil];

    [btn.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];            
}
```

But all i get is a button with a drop shadow. I've linked the quartz core library, ive imported it, i've linked the buttons, ive tried using different types of buttons; i'm Stumped.
Any Ideas whats going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only have one button in your array. What exactly are you trying to do here ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem. It seems you are building for iOS6 [as I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368197/cant-do-custom-uibutton-in-ios6-with-enabled-storyboard-autolayout). I found that Autolayout for storyboards, introduced in iOS6, is causing such problems. Just disable it if you don't use this feature:

1. Open storyboard in Xcode
2. Open properties of storyboard (right pane with properties)
3. Uncheck "Use Autolayout" in "Interface Builder Document" section.

Comment: This is probably correct. I have answered the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the locations and the start/end points for your gradient ?

```
btnGradient.locations  = @[@(0.), @(1.)];
btnGradient.startPoint = (CGPoint){0., 0.};
btnGradient.endPoint   = (CGPoint){0., 1.};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to remove any previously existing `CAGradientLayer` in your button:

```
for(CALayer* layer in btn.layer.sublayers)
    if ([layer isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]])
        [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

and then adding your own.

Comment: [http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/custom-uibutton_iphone/] i downloaded the source and it work i can't see the difference between the my project and that project