# Auto Layout error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I had a similar problem to [this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368197/cant-do-custom-uibutton-in-ios6-with-enabled-storyboard-autolayout). And I used jrturton's suggestion to move the code for customizing the buttons into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. It was working well until I received this error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still
>   required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller.
>   ViewController's implementation needs to send -layoutSubviews to the
>   view to invoke auto layout.'

I'm very clueless on graphics, and the only thing I could think of was to put `[self.view layoutSubviews];` but that didn't fix anything. It worked when I unchecked "Auto Layout" in my Storyboard, but that changed the dimensions of my buttons, and I was wondering if there was another way to fix it?

Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    NSArray *arrayOfButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.decimalButton, self.buttonOne, self.buttonTwo, self.buttonThree, nil];

    for (UIButton *button in arrayOfButtons) {

        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        button.layer.borderWidth = 0.25f;
        button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

        CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        btnGradient.frame = button.bounds;
        btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:122.0f / 255.0f green:188.0f / 255.0f blue:255.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                              (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:96.0f / 255.0f green:171.0f / 255.0f blue:248.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                              nil];
        [button.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: What about calling `[super viewDidLayoutSubviews]`? The docs say the default implementation does nothing, but worth a try.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I had this issue recently, when I wanted to programmatically adjust frame of the view created by storyboard, by providing a `viewDidLayoutSubviews` message handler. Following the instruction from exception message, I tried to add `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` at the end of `-viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and then it worked.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this works. It seems like this should end in infinite recursion, but it doesn't. After calling `[self.view layoutSubviews]`, wouldn't `viewDidLayoutSubviews` get called again, and so on?

Comment: My guess is that there are several passes during which time the auto layouts "settle", i.e. they are progressively marked as satisfied or not until no ambiguity remains.

Comment: You saved me. I thought for sure the error indicated that we should explicitly call `layoutSubviews` *before* the call to the `super` implementation.

Comment: This works, though I called [self.view layoutIfNeeded] instead and that worked, too -- in the docs, it says never to call layoutSubviews directly.

Comment: I guess there's a reason why you got so many votes on this one. We're all confused about how this works, and since cocoa touch is not open source, we can only guess. +1 to Hercrom for the fix. And +1 to @Anna Dickinson for pointing out a better fix.

Comment: [self.view layoutIfNeeded] should be better. But I am not sure if this fix has any side effect on iOS 8?

Comment: This seems to be fixed on iOS8, it also doesn't happen if you place the code into viewWillLayoutSubviews instead