# Weird CAGradientLayer bug on UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, quartz-core, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to apply a small gradient to all the buttons in my ios app. I created a category for UIButton where I added this function which basically add subtitle, border and a gradient layer to the button.

The function is called in view did load:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [_myButton buttonWithSubtitle:@"test subtitle"];

}
```

And the category function

```
- (void)buttonWithSubtitle:(NSString*)subtitleText
{
  UILabel *subTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 100, 30)];
  [subTitle setText:subtitleText];
  [subTitle setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(144.0 / 255.0) green:(144.0 / 255.0) blue:(144.0 / 255.0) alpha:1.0]];
  [subTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  [subTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:12]];
  [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 20, 100, 30)];

  [self setTitle:@"Main title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self addSubview:subTitle];

  CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
  btnGradient.frame = self.bounds;
  btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f / 255.0f green:255.0f / 255.0f blue:255.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                        (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f / 255.0f green:234.0f / 255.0f blue:234.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                        nil];

  [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [self.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
  [self.layer setBorderWidth:0.8f];
  [self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f / 255.0f green:200.0f / 255.0f blue:200.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]];

  [self.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];
}
```

My problem is, when the above function is called, the gradient is clearly visible and the button has the desired design. But, I also have a button type with no subtitle which I setup using an other category function below.

```
- (void)defaultButton
 {
  CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
  btnGradient.frame = self.bounds;
  btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f / 255.0f green:255.0f / 255.0f blue:255.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                        (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f / 255.0f green:234.0f / 255.0f blue:234.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
                        nil];

  [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
  [self.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
  [self.layer setBorderWidth:0.8f];
  [self.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f / 255.0f green:200.0f / 255.0f blue:200.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor]];

  [self.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];
}
```

Using this function called in viewdidload like before results in a button with no gradient or background at all (the button has a clear background color.. I can see my view controller's view background through the button).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [_myButton defaultButton];

}
```

All my buttons are setup as custom button with an image and a default title. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, although I do not know why the code with subtitle works, the problem is, with autolayout enabled, your button does not yet have a frame during the viewDidLoad method.

The gradient must be applied later when there is an layer for the button such as in the method

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

see : [Can't do custom UIButton in iOS6 with enabled storyboard autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368197/cant-do-custom-uibutton-in-ios6-with-enabled-storyboard-autolayout)